# Is there a name for this kind of causal inference from observational data? Using a single model across multiple contexts

Tags: inference, causality, observational-study

Suppose you have two variables A and B, such that A influences B with some coefficient b. What is the correlation between A and B? Well, it depends on the variances of b, so it's going to vary across samples and contexts.

But you can turn that around: If you have covariances across different contexts, then it is more likely that the causal relationship will be uniquely identified, because one unique causal coefficient will give rise to a variety of distinct correlation patterns, and there will only be a small subspace in which confounding or a causal relation in the opposite direction will fit.

More specifically, I'm considering a variant of this. Rather than looking across different contexts, I'm rephrasing the variables as A=A'(x), B=B'(x), embedding them into a family of variable pairs, and considering the relationships A'(x)↔B'(x), A'(y)↔B'(y), .... By making the assumption that the causal relationships are the same across each of the members of the family, as long as the family is sufficiently varied and the assumptions hold, causal inference should be identified.

Is there a name for this method? I haven't seen it used anywhere, I think, but in retrospect it seems fairly obvious, so it seems like it should've been invented before.